# Image inside div disorts

Tags: html, css, image

I'm trying to make clickable image inside div and it's being placed under divs header. I want that this image would be in the same level as Header.
Thanks.

Html:

```
<div class="One"> <h1> One </h1>
<div <a href="One.html">
<img  alt="One" src="One.jpg" width="200" height="200"> </a></div>
</div>
```

Css:

```
.One{
position:absolute;
top:10%;
left:10%;
height: 35%;
width: 50%;
border: 1px solid;  
}
.One h1{
text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: Not sure what you want. But if you just want to click the image, close your div-tag: `<div` -> `<div>`

Comment: You have a mistake in your HTML. it should be `<div> <a href="One.html">`  in line 2   > is missing after `<div`

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to close one of the opening div tags.You also may need to use the whole URL in the hyperlink. Instead of using

```
<a href="One.html">
```

You might want to use

```
<a href="http://mywebsite.com/One.html">
```

Comment: I edited my answer to address an additional issue. This may help.

Comment: Try using the full URL in the hyperlink. I actually open the page that I want to put a link to, and copy and paste the address that way. Hope this works for you.

Answer (score 0):

Are you expecting the following output?

```css
.One{
position:absolute;
top:10%;
left:10%;
height: 35%;
width: 50%;
border: 1px solid;  
}
.One h1{
position:absolute;
left:35%;
}
.One a img {
width:100%;
height:100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="One"> <h1> One </h1>
<a href="One.html">
<img  alt="One" src="https://image.freepik.com/free-vector/prairie-house-with-fowers-and-sunrays-background_293-152.jpg" > </a></div>
```